# JS, link to pushed element

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

how i can push element to a array and after modify it?
Example:

```
//Here new object
var ob = new User({login:"Max", age:22});
//array of existing elements
var users = array[..] //length for example 5
//pushing to array
users.push(ob);
//here im change element data and would like change it in array element (saving data to server, and return ID of saved element)
ob.age = 33;
```

How i shoud do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you posted should work as it is.

JavaScript stores references in the array, so the stored object is the *same* object you pushed.

In case you reassigned the `ob` variable to a different object, you can access the last element with `users[users.length-1]`

Answer (score 0):

`ob` is an object, and `users` has a reference to the object `ob`. So, `users` has already been changed.
If you are using some DB (I guess that you are using mongoDB) , you only have to save `users` to DB.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong to like you, but you can to do this:

1. Find the item you need to modify the location of the array.
2. Then create a new object, to reset the corresponding values.
3. Then the newly created object, back into the array.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRuJrFDeu00 you *really* should work on your english...

Comment: I'm sorry, the answer from automatic translation.